# Проверка, битый ли файл jpg или png в python

Tags: python, png, jpeg

Проверка, есть ли изображение в файле. Файлы разного размера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто пытаетесь открыть этот файл какой-нибудь библиотекой, которая умеет читать картинки и смотрите на её реакцию:

```
from PIL import Image, UnidentifiedImageError

try:
    im = Image.open("/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/skimage/data/rocket.jpg")
    print('Картинка OK!')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('Файл не найден!')
except UnidentifiedImageError:
    print('Это не картинка!')
except Exception as ex:
    print('Другая ошибка:')
    print(ex)
```

Какая именно ошибка будет на ваших битых файлах - это нужно проверять, возможно ошибка будет какая-то другая.